# IIS reverse proxy to nodejs app via https problem

Tags: node.js, ssl, iis

I am building a nodejs api that is hosted by iis. It works perfectly over (using port 5000) http. However, when trying to use the https connection if fails(ssl are installed). I either get a connection failed message or a refused message.

```
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://api.mysite.com:5000/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

Seems like IIS is refusing the connection. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your inbound rules are blocking all HTTPS requests. Revise them please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your url rewrite rule, I found all your https request will match the ReverseProxyInboundRule2 and rewrite to "http://api.mysite.com:5000". I suggest you could firstly check you could access the "http://api.mysite.com:5000".

I guess there is something wrong with this url. It seems you doesn't bind the domain in the IIS binding configuration.

I suggest you could try to open the IIS web application binding to add the domain for the http://api.mysite.com.

[image]

Comment: I had to add two bindings without the https and 5000. on binding for ssl and http. That allowed me to route to the correct page.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the grammar. Two bindings. 1. http and  2. https

Comment: If you feel my answer help you to solve the issue, please mark it as answer. It will help other folks who faces the same issue. Thank you.